# Is it possible to retrieve one hidden form and close another hidden form

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I am using the following code to close and open the hidden form(by checking open appl).    Is it possible to retrieve one hidden form and close another where both the forms corresponds to same one (say form1 hidden at different periods at runtime)

```
var frm = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType() == typeof(FrmAdd_To_Cart));

if (frm != null)
{
    frm.Close(); or frm.show();
}
```

Comment: You need something to differentiate and recognize between the twos. Some public property, even the Tag property set to different values.

Comment: Tag Property? Can You Please explain @Steve

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Tag property to recognize one form from the other

```
FrmAdd_To_Cart formToClose = null;
var frmCartList = Application.OpenForms.OfType<FrmAdd_To_Cart>();
if (frmCartList != null)
{
    foreach(FrmAdd_To_Cart frm in frmCartList)
    {
        // Your logic could be based on the value that you set
        // in the Tag property when you create the form
        // For example you could have a CustomerID stored in the Tag
        // int customerID = Convert.ToInt32(frm.Tag);

        // But probably it is better to have custom public property 
        // in the definition of your FrmAdd_To_Cart form class like
        // if(frm.CustomerID == CurrentCustomer.ID)
        //   .....

        // Or if you want to close the form that you identify with the tag
        if (this.lblBil.Text == frm.Tag.ToString()) 
        {
            formToClose = frm;

            break; // exit the loop and then close                  

            // Can't do this here because this will change 
            // the iterating collection and this is not allowed
            // frm.Close();
        }

    }
    if (formToClose != null)
       formToClose.Close();
}
```

Notice that you could use the OfType extension to get only the forms that you are interested in. Also this means that you have an IEnumerable returned and thus you need to loop using the foreach.

Comment: I dont understand this line " if(frm.CurrentCustomerState == CustomerStateEnum.NotLoggedIn)" .

Comment: You mean to say that everytime i open the frmobject i have to asssign a tag (say customer_id) and check if the tag is equal to the tag of form we wish to close or open. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I have hidden 2 FrmAdd_To_Cart Forms with different formobject tag value(say frmaddtocart.tag = 1 and frmaddtocart = 2 respectively)...
And i tried something like this,......

var frmCartList = Application.OpenForms.OfType<FrmAdd_To_Cart>();
if (frmCartList != null)
{
    foreach(FrmAdd_To_Cart frm in frmCartList)
    {
        int billnum= Convert.ToInt32(frm.Tag);
        if (this.lblBil.Text == billnum)
            {
                frm.Close();
            }
    }
}
/////////// i am getting "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.INVALID OPERATION EXCEPTION"

Comment: You need to exit from the loop before trying to close the form. When you find the for assign it to a different variable. I will update the answer code

Comment: Thanks a million steve :) :) it works perfectly :) :)